# expecting delimiter error converting stringify to json

Tags: python-3.x

i get a json stringify from somewhere and try to convert it to a object by **json.loads()**.... my string is :

```
mystring = "{\"browse\":{\"postList\":{\"p\":1,\"ce\":true,\"token\":\"2C_AmcmNf\",\"c\":\"100\",\"p4\":null,\"p1\":null,\"c4\":null,\"d\":3,\"ic\":4,\"lm\":1549382114,\"c2\":137,\"p2\":5,\"c1\":125,\"hc\":false,\"c3\":null,\"p3\":null,\"image\":\"https:\u002F\u002Fs100u002Fstatic\u002Fthumbnails\u002F1549382114\u002F2C_Am\"cmNf.jpg\"}}}";
```

when i run this:

```
aaaa = regex.sub(r'(\\")', '\"', mystring)  # remove extra \ from string
xx = JSON.loads(aaaa, encoding='utf8')
```

get this error:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/**init**.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 359, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 7249 (char 7248)

what should i do? to fix this problem in standard mode

i want a class dict so i can say `xx[browse]` !!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
data = json.dumps(mystring)
print(json.loads(data))
>>>{"browse":{"postList":{"p":1,"ce":true,"token":"2C_AmcmNf","c":"100","p4":null,"p1":null,"c4":null,"d":3,"ic":4,"lm":1549382114,"c2":137,"p2":5,"c1":125,"hc":false,"c3":null,"p3":null,"image":"https:\u002F\u002Fs100u002Fstatic\u002Fthumbnails\u002F1549382114\u002F2C_Am"cmNf.jpg"}}}
```

Comment: sorry but in this mode it gives me  <class str> but i want <class dict>.... @Pradam

Comment: @NimaAnsari your json have an issue in key image value.

Comment: You can still say `xx["browse"]`. I don't see why or how `browse` can be a variable when you load from string - so you're either just missing the quotes or you have to do something more.

Comment: Just change the last statement of this snippet to `xx = json.loads(data)` before `xx["browse"]`

Comment: @AnoopRDesai my dear, please test it before comment... i want to access attributes by name not by integer... in your answers i take this error: print(xx['browse'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers