# Safely parsing nested json double quotes

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-3.9

The issue:

```
>>> import json
>>> json_str='{"message": "John said "come here!""}'
>>> json.loads(json_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ram/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/ram/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/ram/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 25 (char 24)
```

Then I attempted to escape the double-quotes. Like so:

```
>>> json_str='{"message": "John said \"come here!\""}'
>>> json.loads(json_str)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ram/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/ram/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/ram/.pyenv/versions/3.9.6/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 25 (char 24)
```

The following works though:

```
>>> json_str='{"message": "John said \'come here!\'"}'
>>> json.loads(json_str)
{'message': "John said 'come here!'"}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to flag the json library to be more forgiving (helps me leave json parsing to the json library)?

PS: Following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54534871/expecting-delimiter-error-converting-stringify-to-json), I attempted the following:

```
>>> data=json.dumps('{"message":"John said "hello!""}')
>>> print(data)
"{\"message\":\"John said \"hello!\"\"}"
>>> dict = json.loads(data)
>>> print(dict)
{"message":"John said "hello!""}
>>> print(dict['message'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
>>> print(dict[0])
{
```

The last json.loads is returning a string instead of dict. But the correctly escaped quotes in data did sound promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use either a raw string or double backslashes so that you both escape the backslashes in python as well as in the json string so that `json.loads` can see the backslashes.

```py
>>> json.loads(r'{"message": "John said \"come here!\""}')
{'message': 'John said "come here!"'}
>>> json.loads('{"message": "John said \\"come here!\\""}')
{'message': 'John said "come here!"'}
```